# populate array with posts

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, get-posts, options

I want to generate an array of custom post types to add it to a options array.
I'm doing this to show a checkbox group populated with custom post type.

I have this array:

```
'options' => array (  
    'one' => array (  
        'label' => 'Option One',  
        'value' => 'one'  
    ),  
    'two' => array (  
        'label' => 'Option Two',  
        'value' => 'two'  
    ),  
    'three' => array (  
        'label' => 'Option Three',  
        'value' => 'three'  
    ),  
    'four' => array (  
        'label' => 'Option Four',  
        'value' => 'four'  
    )  
)
```

How can i replace this with a custom post type?
i'm trying this:

```
function get_sponsors()
{
    $args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'movies'
    );

    $my_movies = get_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );

    return $my_movies;
}
```

I'm using the code in this article: [Reusable Custom Meta Boxes Part 2](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/reusable-custom-meta-boxes-part-2-advanced-fields/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the posts you can easily put them in another array & then return that array

```
function get_sponsors()
{
    $args = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'movies'
    );

    $my_movies = get_posts($args);

    $options = array();
    foreach($my_movies as $m)
        $options[$m->ID] = array(
            'label' => $m->post_title,
            'value' => $m->ID
        );

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: that works perfect! thk